# In java how do I have a class both implements MouseListener and throws IOException?

Tags: java, ioexception, mouselistener, implements, throws

The throws IOException is for input from a file.

Answer (score 4):

something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
class Foo implements MouseListener {
    void io() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("foo");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        fileReader.read();
        // ...
    }
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        try {
            io();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But I would argue that if you're needing to do any IO, it's probably best not to do it in the EventQueue thread as it may cause hold ups (causing the GUI to become unresponsive). Creating a new Runnable for a new Thread or Executor would be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Classes don't throw exceptions, methods do.

```
public class Foo implements MouseListener {
    public void throwingUp() throws IOException {
        // ... Code that could throw IOE
    }
    // ... MouseListener impl
}
```

Comment: You could throw a RuntimeException in a static initializer.  But since Zane wants to throw an IOException, that won't do.

Comment: @emory Nor would you have to ask how, either, since RTEs aren't declared.

Comment: I thought they did, but when I try to have the method throws IOException it says "mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in TicTacToe.ClickListener cannot
implement mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in
java.awt.event.MouseListener; overridden method does not throw
java.io.IOException" what does this mean?

I feel silly right now

Comment: @Zane See Ray's answer; he read your mind better than I did. It's important to be specific when asking questions. Nutshell: the `MouseListener` methods can't throw it, but they can wrap a method throwing an IOE and throw a `RuntimeException` (if that's reasonable in your app).

Comment: @Dave yeah, I understand now and got my program working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Classes do not throw IOExceptions, methods do.  Your class can implement MouseListener, but those methods (mouseClicked, mousePressed etc...) cannot throw IOExceptions.  You'll have to wrap them in a RuntimeException (or a subclass).  e.g.

```
   @Override
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      try {
         methodThatMightThrowAnIOException();
      }
      catch (IOException ioe)
      {
         throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
      }
   }
```

Other methods, like `methodThatMightThrowAnIOException()`, can throw IOExceptions.